# Выход за пределы памяти при удалении элемента списка

Tags: c++, list

Есть функция для удаления узлов списка PrimalDelete, содержащих простые числа. Список двусвязный.

Она работает, только если содержится одно простое число в узле, или если имеются два узла с любой комбинацией. При введении данных : 4 3 8 5, функция выдает ошибку : data  CXX0030: ошибка: невозможно вычислить выражение, после удаления первого простого числа - 3.

Скорее всего проблема с условием, но у меня не получается разобраться, помогите пожалуйста.

```
template <class T>
bool TDList <T>::Delete(int pos)
{
        if (n == 0) 
                return false;
        else if (n == 1) { 
                delete first;
                first = NULL;
                last = NULL;
        }
        else if (pos <= 1) {
                TElem <T> *p = first->next;
                delete first;
                p->prev = NULL;
                first = p;
        }
        else if (pos >= n) { 
                TElem <T> *p = last->prev;
                delete last;
                p->next = NULL;
                last = p;
        }
        else {
                TElem <T> *p = first;
                for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) 
                        p = p->next;
                TElem <T> *p1 = p->prev;
                TElem <T> *p2 = p->next;
                delete p;
                p1->next = p2;
                p2->prev = p1;
        }
        n--;
        return true;
}
 template <class T>
 void TDList <T>::PrimalDelete()
 {
    bool i;
    int pos = 0; 
        int k = 1;
        TElem <T> *p = first;
  while (p != NULL) 
  { cout<<"Вывод адреса узла списка: "<<p<<endl;
        i = PrimalSearch(p);
        if (i == 1)
        {
            pos = k;
            Delete(pos);
            k--;    
        }
        k++;
        if(first == NULL){
            break;
        }
        if (first == last){
            break;
        }
        if (last == NULL){
        break;
        }
        p = p->next;


   }
 }
      template <class T>
 bool TDList <T>::PrimalSearch(TElem<T>* p)
 {
     if(p->data==1){ 
         return false;}
    for(int d=2; d*d<=p->data; d++){ 
        if(fmod(p->data,d)==0) 
            return false;
        }
  return true;
 }
```

Полный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct TElem
{
        T data; 
        TElem *next; 
        TElem *prev;

};

template <class T> 
class TDList
{
        int n; 
        TElem <T> *first; 
        TElem <T> *last; 

public:
        TDList();
        TDList(int size); 
        TDList(const TDList& source); 
        ~TDList(); 
        void Add(T data, int pos); 
        void PrimalDelete();
        bool PrimalSearch(TElem<T>* p);
        bool Delete(int pos); 
        int SearchData(T data); 
        bool SearchPos(int pos, T& data); 
        void Print(); 

};

template <class T>
TDList <T>::TDList()
{
        n = 0;
        first = NULL;
        last  = NULL;
}

template <class T>
TDList <T>::TDList(int size)
{
        n  = size;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                Add(rand() % 100, n + 1);
}

template <class T>
TDList <T>::TDList(const TDList <T>& source)
{
        n = 0;
        first = NULL;
        last  = NULL;
        TElem <T> *p = source.first;
        while (p != NULL) {
                Add(p->data, n + 1);
                n++;
                p = p->next;
        }
}

template <class T>
TDList <T>::~TDList()
{
        TElem <T> *p = first;
        while (p != NULL) {
                TElem <T> *q = p;
                p = p->next;
                delete q;
        }
}

template <class T>
void TDList <T>::Add(T data, int pos)
{
        TElem <T> *p = new TElem <T>;
        p->data = data;
        p->next = NULL;
        p->prev = NULL;
        if (n == 0) { 
                first = p;
                last = p;
        }
        else if (pos <= 1) { 
                p->next = first;
                first->prev = p;
                first = p; 
                cout<<p<<endl;
        }
        else if (pos > n) { 
                last->next = p;
                p->prev = last;
                last = p;
        }
        else {
                TElem <T> *p1 = first;
                for (int i = 0; i < pos - 2; i++) 
                        p1 = p1->next;
                TElem <T> *p2 = p1->next;
                p1->next = p;
                p2->prev = p;
                p->next = p2;
                p->prev = p1;
        }
        n++; //cout<<p<<endl;
}


template <class T>
bool TDList <T>::Delete(int pos)
{
        if (n == 0) 
                return false;
        else if (n == 1) { 
                delete first;
                first = NULL;
                last = NULL;
        }
        else if (pos <= 1) {
                TElem <T> *p = first->next;
                delete first;
                p->prev = NULL;
                first = p;
        }
        else if (pos >= n) { 
                TElem <T> *p = last->prev;
                delete last;
                p->next = NULL;
                last = p;
        }
        else {
                TElem <T> *p = first;
                for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) 
                        p = p->next;
                TElem <T> *p1 = p->prev;
                TElem <T> *p2 = p->next;
                delete p;
                p1->next = p2;
                p2->prev = p1;
        }
        n--;
        return true;
}
 template <class T>
 void TDList <T>::PrimalDelete()
 {
    bool i;
    int pos = 0; 
        int k = 1;
        TElem <T> *p = first;
  while (p != NULL) 
  { cout<<"Вывод адреса узла списка: "<<p<<endl;
        i = PrimalSearch(p);
        if (i == 1)
        {
            pos = k;
            Delete(pos);
            k--;
        }
        k++;
        if(first == NULL){
            break;
        }
        if (first == last){
            break;
        }
        if (last == NULL){
        break;
        }
        p = p->next;
}
 }
      template <class T>
 bool TDList <T>::PrimalSearch(TElem<T>* p)
 {
     if(p->data==1){ 
         return false;}
    for(int d=2; d*d<=p->data; d++){ 
        if(fmod(p->data,d)==0) 
            return false;
        }
  return true;
 }

template <class T>
int TDList <T>::SearchData(T data)
{
        int pos = 0; 
        int k = 1;
        TElem <T> *p = first;
        while (p != NULL) {
                if (p->data == data) {
                        pos = k;
                        break;
                }
                k++;
                p = p->next;
        }
        return pos;
}

template <class T>
bool TDList <T>::SearchPos(int pos, T& data)
{
        if (pos < 1 || pos > n)
                return false;
        TElem <T> *p = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) 
                p = p->next;
        data = p->data;
        return true;
}

template <class T>
void TDList <T>::Print()
{
        cout <<("list: ");
        TElem <T> *p = first;
        while (p != NULL) {
                cout << p->data << " ";
                p = p->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
}



void Menu()
{
    cout <<("1 - добавить элемент\n");
    cout <<("2 - удалить элемент\n");
    cout <<("3 - поиск элемента по значению\n");
    cout <<("4 - поиск элемента по номеру\n");
    cout <<("5 - удаление из списка простых чисел\n");
    cout <<("6 - вывести список на экран\n");
    cout <<("Esc выход\n\n");
}


int main()
{
        setlocale(0,""); 
        Menu();
        TDList <float> list; 
        float f;
        int pos;
        bool res;
        const int MaxInt=2147483647; 
    while (1) {
        char c = getch(); 
        switch (c) {
        case '1':
                        cout <<("Введите элемент для добавления: ");
                        cin >> f;
                        cout <<("1 - в начало; 2 - в конец; 3 (или любая другая клавиша) - в заданную позицию\n");
                        c = getch();
                        switch (c) {
                        case '1':
                                list.Add(f, 1); //cout<<p<<endl;
                                break;
                        case '2':
                                list.Add(f, MaxInt); 
                                break;
                        default:
                                cout <<("Введите номер позиции: ");
                                cin >> pos;
                                list.Add(f, pos); 
                                //cout<<p<<endl;
                                break;
                        }
                        cout <<("Элемент добавлен\n");
            break;
        case '2':
                        cout <<("1 - из начала; 2 - из конца; 3 (или любая другая клавиша) - из заданной позиции\n");
                        c = getch();
                        switch (c) {
                        case '1':
                                res = list.Delete(1); 
                                break;
                        case '2':
                                res = list.Delete(MaxInt); 
                                break;
                        default:
                                cout <<("Введите номер позиции: ");
                                cin >> pos;
                                res = list.Delete(pos); 
                                break;
                        }
                        if (res)
                                cout <<("Элемент удален\n");
                        else
                                cout <<("Элемент не удален, т.к. список пуст\n");
            break;
        case '3':
                        cout <<("Введите элемент для поиска: ");
                        cin >> f;
                        pos = list.SearchData(f);
                        if (pos != 0) {
                                cout <<("Элемент найден в позиции ");
                                cout << pos << endl;
                        }
                        else
                                cout <<"Элемент не найден\n";
            break;
        case '4':
                        cout <<"Введите номер элемента для поиска: ";
                        cin >> pos;
                        res = list.SearchPos(pos, f);
                        if (res) {
                                cout <<"Найденный элемент ";
                                cout << f << endl;
                        }
                        else
                                cout <<"Элемент не найден\n";
            break;

        case '5':
                list.PrimalDelete();
                cout <<"Все простые числа удалены\n ";
            break;
        case '6':
                  list.Print(); 
                        break;


        case 27:
            return 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а можете добавить и `header` `TDList` и как вы все вызываете? 
Не очень понятно, что за `n` в `Delete`.

Comment: @raviga, n - количество узлов в списке. Обновлю код, добавив всё.

Comment: Может в конструкторе с размером, в Add нужно передавать i + 1 вместо n + 1? (Особо код не смотрел)

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup, зачем?

Comment: @AnnaErion Допустим Вы передаете в конструктор значение 10. n устанавливается в 10, начинается цикл до 10, а в первый вызов Add передается n + 1, т.е. 11. Теперь выполните Add с аргументом 11 для пустого списка

Comment: @AnnaErion Ошибочка вышла. Не i + 1. Просто i. Ещё проблема в том, что в конструкторе TDList(int size) Вы делаете n = size (т.е. Вы сразу установили размер списка), а метод Add увеличивает n. Думаю лучше установить n в 0 и сделать условием цикла i < size.

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup, Add(T data, int pos), передаём позицию и значение узла, а n просто прибавляется при каждом заполнении нового узла.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101784/discussion-between-not-bjarne-stroustrup-and-anna-erion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что функция Delete в PrimalDelete удаляет узел на который указывает указатель p, после чего PrimalDelete пытается выполнить код p = p->next.
Вот отредактированный код функции PrimalDelete:

```
template <class T>
void TDList <T>::PrimalDelete()
{
    bool i;
    int pos = 0;
    int k = 1;
    TElem <T>* p = first;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Show address: " << p << endl;
        i = PrimalSearch(p);
        if (i == 1)
        {
            pos = k;
            p = p->next;
            Delete(pos);
        }
        else
        {
            k++;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```